# IOS / Swift2 - List all files in remote directory

Tags: ios, nginx, swift2

I have a server running nginx. I have a directory in my server where I have several audio files. I replaced my real url by "url".

How can I list all files in that directory in a table.

When I print weContent I get:

**403 Forbidden**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "url")!
    //self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        // Will happen when task completes
        if let urlContent = data {
            let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(webContent)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.webView.loadHTMLString(String(webContent!), baseURL: nil)
            })
        } else {
            // Show error message
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 403 error usually means that the user or group doesn't have permission to access to the resource you are requesting.

You should try changing the permissions on the directory you are trying to access to: o+r or change the owner of the directory to the appropriate user. (I generally use apache servers, the user is www)

Nginx provides it's own documentation on 403 errors [here](http://nginxlibrary.com/403-forbidden-error/)

Comment: The permission for the directory is drwxr-xr-x.

Comment: The owner is my user in the server. I guess this is not the correct def?

Comment: Probably not. Using apache, the owner for my website files is usually `_www:_www`. I sometime have to set it using `sudo chown -R www:www .` from the root directory for the server.

Comment: Already did that: sudo chown -R my-user:www-data /webdirectory &
sudo chmod -R 0755 /webdirectory